# How to solve this combinations with repetitions problem using generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, combinations

Find the number of solutions to  :
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 10$$
where none of the variables can be the number $3$.

I can solve this with Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, but I really love solving this kind of problem with generating functions. I did not manage to solve it with generating functions , this is my try:

I have $5$ variables. None of them can be the number $3$.
Need to find : coefficient of $${x^{10}}$$
so:

- $x_1$ can be :  $0 , 1 , 2, 4 ,5 , 6, \ldots$ to infinity, that means:

$$1 + x + {x^2} + {x^4} + {x^5} + {x^6} + .....$$ 
and this is relevant for all of the five variables so thats means total:
$${(1 + x + {x^2} + {x^4} + ...)^5}$$

but I can't find the generating function of this series.
I tried to multiply the series by $x$ and then subtract the original series from the multiplied one
$$\begin{array}{l}1 + x + {x^2} + {x^{{4^{}}}} + ...\\ - {\rm{ }}x + {x^2} + {x^3} + {x^4} + ...\end{array}
$$
and I get:
$${\left( {\frac{{1 - {x^3}}}{{1 - x}}} \right)^5}
$$

but the final solution after I'm using binomial expansion is $1$, and that's not correct.

Can I get help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some purpose for all the comments in the source? It is slightly inconvenient to see it flash by.

Comment: so remove all my explanations ? 
I want it to be comfratble to read.
I wrote what I tried for solving it.

Comment: Not the explanations! The lines starting with '%...' in the source!

Comment: I mean as @martini said this stuff % MathType! MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2a  aatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLb vyNv2Ca  erbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1 BTfMBaeXatL  xBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwz YbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiV  u0Je9sqqrpepC0xbb  L8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9 Lq-Jc9

Comment: this is how you seeing my messege ?

Comment: Yes, before it comiles. It is in the source. click [edit] to see it. It does dissapear later but it is still inconvenoent. Why is it there? Do you use some tool to create the math?

Comment: I used MathType. they have cut and paste options for stackexchange

Comment: OKay. Thanks for the info.  I am  not sure why this tool adds this. But before I do not know I will not touch it.

Comment: so you see tonly he sourcecode  ?

Comment: No. But I have a slow computer so I see it briefly *at first.* The reason I brought it up is that it is inconvenient to have it their, mainly when one wants to edit the post.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Inclusion–exclusion principle.

Without the restriction $x_i\neq 3$ you have
$$\binom{10+5-1}{10}$$
solutions.

Now you need to check how many bad cases you have.
Denote the set of all solutions with $x_i=3$ by $A_i$.
Your bad cases are $$A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup A_5.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm trying to solve with this approach.
so S0 = |u| = all the solution for this problem which is what you wrote .
so now x1 have three balls for example
then I've left with  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 (7) balls and 4 cells 

so  ->          000 |    |    |   |  so this is D(4,7) and I have totall 5 like this so 

s1 = |A| +|B|+|C|+|D|+|E| = 5 * D(4,7)  ? am I in the right direction ?

Comment: Yes, and now you need to compute $|A_i\cap A_j|$ and to notice that there are $\binom{5}{2}$ pairs.

Comment: yes. I solved it yestarday. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can express your close-to-geometric sum as the difference between sums, i.e.

$$f(x)=\sum_{k\ge 0} x^k -x^3=\frac{1}{1-x}-x^3=\frac{1-x^3+x^4}{1-x}$$

Then we have

$$F(x)=\left(\frac{1-x^3+x^4}{1-x}\right)^5=\sum_{j\ge0}\binom{j+4}{4}x^j\cdot\sum_{a+b+c=5}\binom{5}{a,b,c}(-1)^bx^{3b+4c}$$

and equating coefficients we have that $10=j+3b+4c\ \to j=10-3b-4c$ and $j,b,c\ge 0$ and $b+c\le 5\ \to c\le 5-b$. So

$$[x^{10}]F(x)=\sum_{b+c\le 5}\binom{14-3b-4c}{4}\binom{5}{5-b-c,b,c}(-1)^b$$

You can simplify this sum seeing that $14-3b-4c\ge 4$ and so on.

Alternatively you can take the $[x^{10}]$ coefficient from the Maclaurin series of $F(x)$ using some CAS.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ \frac{1-x^3}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2 $$
so in $(1+x+x^2)^5$ you are counting only the solutions with $0 \le x_i \le 2$ of which there is in fact only one.

Note that 
$$ (1-x)\sum_{i\ne 3} x^i = \sum_{i\ne 3} x^i - \sum_{i\ne 0,4} x^i 
  = 1 + x^4 - x^3
$$
So we are left with 
$$ \left(\frac{1 - x^3 + x^4}{1-x}\right)^5 $$
Now do your expansion again.

---

Addendum: We have, 
$$ (1-x^3+x^4)^5 = \sum_{i+j+k = 5} \frac{5!}{i!j!k!} (-1)^jx^{3j+4k} $$

Comment: I know to solve this
$$\frac{1}{{{{(1 - x)}^5}}} = {(1 - x)^{ - 5}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaca
% aIXaaabaGaaiikaiaaigdacqGHsislcaWG4bGaaiykamaaCaaaleqa
% baGaaGynaaaaaaGccqGH9aqpcaGGOaGaaGymaiabgkHiTiaadIhaca
% GGPaWaaWbaaSqabeaacqGHsislcaaI1aaaaaaa!4292!
$$

Comment: but how to solve the trinomial
$${(1 - x)^{ - 5}}*{(1 - {x^3} + {x^4})^5}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaaiikaiaaig
% dacqGHsislcaWG4bGaaiykamaaCaaaleqabaGaeyOeI0IaaGynaaaa
% kiaacQcacaGGOaGaaGymaiabgkHiTiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqaaiaaio
% daaaGccqGHRaWkcaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabeaacaaI0aaaaOGaaiykamaa
% CaaaleqabaGaaGynaaaaaaa!4537!
$$

Comment: Added somehing @idandi

Comment: i+j+k = 5 means that whenever 1 = 0 so, j=1, k = 4 ? and vice versa ?
I thought it will be simpler with generating functions.
I guess its more practical solveing it with another method